# Oracle: return the result set from a CTE from a inline table function

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, common-table-expression, user-defined-functions

I am able to get a similiar function working in TSQL but I am a relative newbie to PL/SQL, I'm hopeing someone can explain to me why this function declaration will not compile.
t_interval_list_table is a table type of objects t_interval which has a single attribute of varchar2(20).  Interval_Get_udf just returns a formatted string of type varchar(2)

```
create or replace
FUNCTION  fn_ExplodeIntervals (
  startTime IN timestamp,
  endTime IN timestamp,
  inputInterval IN int)
  RETURN t_interval_list_table   AS  intervalList t_interval_list_table := t_interval_list_table()
BEGIN

 with SET0 as( select 1 from dual union all select 1 from dual)
   , SET1 as ( select 1 from SET0 s1, SET0 s2)
   , SET2 as ( select 1 from SET1 s1, SET1 s2)
   , SET3 as ( select 1 from SET3 s1, SET3 s2)
   , SET4 as ( select 1 from SET4 s1, SET4 s2)
   , ControlSet AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1 from Dual)) rid  FROM SET4)

  select t_interval(Interval_Get_udf(TO_TIMESTAMP(startTime, 'dd/mm/yyyy') + rid/24 , 1))
  into intervalList
  from ControlSet;

  RETURN intervalList;

END fn_ExplodeIntervals;
```

Comment: Would you mind adding the error message to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably can simplify the query in your PL/SQL procedure:

```
SELECT t_interval(Interval_Get_udf(TRUNC(startTime) + ROWNUM/24 , 1))
BULK COLLECT INTO intervalList
FROM dual 
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 65536
```

That might get rid of the error.

Comment: is the type insertion correct I get a error ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected T_INTERVAL got T_INTERVAL_LIST_TABLE

Comment: Please add the full type definitions and the signature of the Interval_Get_udf function into your question. Then we are able to answer with code that we were able to test first.

Comment: I've made some tests on an Oracle system and tried to guess the data types from your description. What was missing was the "BULK COLLECT" and the semicolon Jeff Moore mentioned. Furthermore, I've used TRUNC instead of the TO_TIMESTAMP since you probably want to chop off the time part of the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to read this one so I'm probably wrong...
Are you just missing the semi-colon at the end of the following: 
t_interval_list_table := t_interval_list_table();